# screen a script with env variables

Tags: environment-variables, gnu-screen

I have a python script that I run by passing some arguments as environment variables:

```
param=1 length=5 python myscript.py
```

I want to run it inside a `screen`. I tried `screen -m param=1 length=5 python myscript.py` but this does not work, I get the error "Cannot exec param=1, no such file or directory". How can I still run this script within a screen?

Comment: Can't you use something like `screen -m bash -c 'param=1 length=5 python myscript.py'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
param=1 length=5 screen -m python myscript.py
```

#### Example

```
$ cat myscript.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print(os.environ["param"], os.environ["length"])
raw_input()
```

If we run this command:

```
$ param=1 length=5 screen -m python myscript.py
```

The output appears:

```
('1', '5')
```

(For python3, replace `raw_input` with `input`.  Also, note that the output will display slightly differently.)